# What's the definition of nondegenerate?

Tags: vector-spaces, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

[image: screenshort from page 11 of Neukirch]

The above picture is from page 11 of Neukirch's "Algebraic Number Theory".

In the proof, there is a sentence as follows:

> Then $1,\theta,\cdots,\theta^{n-1}$ is a basis with respect to which the form $(x,y)$ is given by the matrix $M=(Tr_{L|K}(\theta^{i-1}\theta^{j-1}))_{i,j=1,\cdots,n}$.

If we set $x=r_11+r_2\theta+\cdots+r_n\theta^{n-1}$ and $y=t_11+t_2\theta+\cdots+t_n\theta^{n-1}$,

then we have

$$(x,y)=Tr_{L|K}(xy)=
\left[ \begin{matrix}
 r_{1} & r_{2} 
 &\cdots&
 r_{n}
\end{matrix}\right]
\left[ \begin{matrix}
 \sigma_{1}1&\sigma_{2}1& \cdots &\sigma_n1 \\
  \sigma_{1}\theta &\sigma_{2}\theta& \cdots &\sigma_n\theta\\
  \vdots&\vdots&\cdots & \vdots\\
 \sigma_1\theta^{n-1}& \sigma_2\theta^{n-1}& \cdots&\sigma_n\theta^{n-1}
\end{matrix}\right]
\left[ \begin{matrix}
 \sigma_{1}1&\sigma_{1}\theta& \cdots &\sigma_1\theta^{n-1} \\
  \sigma_{2}1&\sigma_{2}\theta& \cdots &\sigma_2\theta^{n-1}\\
  \vdots&\vdots&\cdots & \vdots\\
 \sigma_n1& \sigma_n\theta& \cdots&\sigma_n\theta^{n-1}
\end{matrix}\right]
\left[ \begin{matrix}
 t_{1} \\
 t_{2} \\ 
 \vdots\\
 t_{n}
\end{matrix}\right] =
\left[ \begin{matrix}
 r_{1} & r_{2} 
 &\cdots&
 r_{n}
\end{matrix}\right]
M
\left[ \begin{matrix}
 t_{1} \\
 t_{2} \\ 
 \vdots\\
 t_{n}
\end{matrix}\right] 
$$

What's the definition of nondegenerate?

Comment: What makes you think we can draw this conclusion?

Comment: E.g. this is not true for $\mathbb C/\mathbb R$, with basis $1, i$ and $x, y = 1, i$.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Then what's the definition of nondegenerate?

Comment: A bilinear form $(\cdot, \cdot)$ is called non-degenerate if for each $x \neq 0$ there is a $y \neq 0$ such that $(x,y) \neq 0$.

Comment: @MeesdeVries I made a mistake. Thank you very much!